# Going from overleaf to TexMaker -> encoding problems

Tags: texmaker, overleaf

I have been writing a document on Overleaf for a while. I will now go travelling without internet and I would like to download this and open it in TexMaker.
However there seems to be an encoding issue. My document should be in UTF-8 (I used the command `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) but Tex Maker does not recognize it.
What should I do ?

Comment: TeXmaker encodes in UTF8 by default, like most modern editors. It also suggests to use an encoding when it doesn't recognise utf8, and has the capability to convert to UTF8.

Comment: The documentation says "Before compiling your first document, you must set the encoding used by the editor ("Configure Texmaker" -> "Editor" -> "Editor Font Encoding"). Then, you should use the same encoding in the preamble of yours TeX documents (example : \usepackage[latin]{inputenc}, if you use the "ISO-8859-1" encoding for the editor)" cf http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html

Comment: Just for information, all text files on Overleaf are UTF8, even those you uploaded from somewhere else (Overleaf automatically converts them to UTF8)

Comment: Any updates here?